# glBufferSubData between glDrawArrays calls mangling data

Tags: c++, opengl

It seems like `glBufferSubData` is overwriting or somehow mangling data between my `glDrawArrays` calls.  I'm working in Windows 7 64bit, with that latest drivers for my Nvidia GeForce GT520M CUDA 1GB.

I have 2 models, each with an animation.  The models have 1 mesh, and that mesh is stored in the same VAO.  They also have 1 animation each, and the bone transformations to be used for rendering the mesh is stored in the same VBO.

My workflow looks like this:

- calculate bone transformation matrices for a model
- load bone transformation matrices into opengl using `glBufferSubData`, then bind the buffer
- render the models mesh using `glDrawArrays`

For one model, this works (at least, mostly - sometimes I get weird gaps in between the vertices).

However, for more than one model, it looks like bone transformation matrix data is getting mixed up between the rendering calls to the meshes.

[Single Model Animated Windows](http://jarrettchisholm.com/static/videos/single_model_animated_windows.vob)
[Two Models Animated Windows](http://jarrettchisholm.com/static/videos/two_models_animated_windows.vob)

I load my bone transformation data like so:

```
void Animation::bind()
{
    glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, bufferId_);
    glBufferSubData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0, currentTransforms_.size() * sizeof(glm::mat4), &currentTransforms_[0]);
    bindPoint_ = openGlDevice_->bindBuffer( bufferId_ );
}
```

And I render my mesh like so:

```
void Mesh::render()
{
    glBindVertexArray(vaoId_);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices_.size());
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

If I add a call to `glFinish()` after my call to `render()`, it works just fine!  This seems to indicate to me that, for some reason, the transformation matrix data for one animation is 'bleeding' over to the next animation.

How could this happen?  I am under the impression that if I called `glBufferSubData` while that buffer was in use (i.e. for a `glDrawArrays` for example), then it would block.  Is this not the case?

It might be worth mentioning that this same code works just fine in Linux.

Note: Related to a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19872471/opengl-animations-work-in-linux-but-not-windows), which I deleted.

**Mesh Loading Code:**

```
void Mesh::load()
{
    LOG_DEBUG( "loading mesh '" + name_ +"' into video memory." );

    // create our vao
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vaoId_);
    glBindVertexArray(vaoId_);

    // create our vbos
    glGenBuffers(5, &vboIds_[0]);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboIds_[0]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices_.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3), &vertices_[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboIds_[1]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textureCoordinates_.size() * sizeof(glm::vec2), &textureCoordinates_[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboIds_[2]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normals_.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3), &normals_[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboIds_[3]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colors_.size() * sizeof(glm::vec4), &colors_[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);
    glVertexAttribPointer(3, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    if (bones_.size() == 0)
    {
        bones_.resize( vertices_.size() );
        for (auto& b : bones_)
        {
            b.weights = glm::vec4(0.25f);
        }
    }

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboIds_[4]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bones_.size() * sizeof(VertexBoneData), &bones_[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(4);
    glVertexAttribIPointer(4, 4, GL_INT, sizeof(VertexBoneData), (const GLvoid*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(5);
    glVertexAttribPointer(5, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexBoneData), (const GLvoid*)(sizeof(glm::ivec4)));

    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

**Animation UBO Setup:**

```
void Animation::setupAnimationUbo()
{
    bufferId_ = openGlDevice_->createBufferObject(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, Constants::MAX_NUMBER_OF_BONES_PER_MESH * sizeof(glm::mat4), &currentTransforms_[0]);
}
```

where `Constants::MAX_NUMBER_OF_BONES_PER_MESH` is set to 100.

In `OpenGlDevice`:

```
GLuint OpenGlDevice::createBufferObject(GLenum target, glmd::uint32 totalSize, const void* dataPointer)
{
    GLuint bufferId = 0;
    glGenBuffers(1, &bufferId);
    glBindBuffer(target, bufferId);

    glBufferData(target, totalSize, dataPointer, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(target, 0);

    bufferIds_.push_back(bufferId);

    return bufferId;
}
```

Comment: ooo interesting - I updated my question with that data.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @AndonM.Coleman.  I added `glBufferData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, currentTransforms_.size() * sizeof(glm::mat4), NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);` before my call to `glBufferSubData`, but I get the same results.  I'm not sure exactly how to do mapping/unmapping, I'll look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those usage flags are mostly correct for this scenario, though you might consider trying `GL_STREAM_DRAW`.

Your driver appears to be failing to implicitly synchronize for some reason, so you might want to try a technique that eliminates the need for synchronization in the first place. I would suggest **Buffer Orphaning**: call `glBufferData (...)` with NULL for the data pointer prior to sending data. This will allow commands that are currently using the UBO to continue using the original data store without forcing synchronization, since you will allocate a new data store before sending new data. When the earlier mentioned commands finish the original data store will be orphaned and the GL implementation will free it.

In newer OpenGL implementations you can use `glInvalidateBuffer[Sub]Data (...)` to hint the driver into doing what was discussed above. Likewise, you can use `glMapBufferRange (...)` with appropriate flags to control all of this behavior more explicitly. Unmapping will implicitly flush and synchronize access to a buffer object unless told otherwise, this might get your driver to do its job if you do not want to mess around with synchronization-free buffer update logic.

Most of what I mentioned is discussed in more detail [here](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object_Streaming#Buffer_re-specification).

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use `glInvalidateBufferData`, as I need to support OpenGL 3.2, but I'll look into `glMapBufferRange(...)`.

Comment: Using `glMapBufferRange` and `glUnmapBuffer` together seems to have fixed the problem.  Thanks @Andon!