# OpenGL Flicker with glBufferSubData

Tags: c++, opengl

I have some terrible flickering happening with a very simple OpenGL setup. I'm using GLFW for windowing and context creation. It is my understanding that you should clear the frame, submit draw calls, then swap buffers. I'm attempting to render a bunch of 2D quads with some batching of transform data within draw calls. Here is my actual rendering routine, called once per simulation step:

```
glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

glUseProgram( m_shader );

// Retrieve shader uniforms
int pos = glGetAttribLocation( m_shader, "position" );
int texCoord = glGetAttribLocation( m_shader, "texCoord" );
int texture = glGetUniformLocation( m_shader, "texture" );
int transforms = glGetUniformLocation( m_shader, "transforms" );

// Bind the quad mesh
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_quad );

// Setup the transforms texture
glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE0 + 1 );
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, m_transformBufferTexture );
glTexBuffer( GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, GL_RGBA32F, m_transformBuffer );
glUniform1i( transforms, 1 );

// Setup stride
glEnableVertexAttribArray( pos );
glEnableVertexAttribArray( texCoord );
glVertexAttribPointer( pos, 4, GL_FLOAT, false, sizeof( Vertex ), (void *)offsetof( Vertex, p ) );
glVertexAttribPointer( texCoord, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, sizeof( Vertex ), (void *)offsetof( Vertex, uv ) );

// Render each batch
for(unsigned i = 0; i < m_batches.Size( ); ++i)
{
  SpriteBatch batch = m_batches[i];
  unsigned count = batch.end - batch.begin + 1;
  unsigned textureID = batch.begin->m_texture->ID( );

  // Copy batch transforms into the transform buffer
  int j = 0;
  for(;;)
  {
    memcpy( m_transforms + j, &batch.begin->m_tx, sizeof( float ) * 6 );
    ++j;

    if(batch.begin == batch.end)
      break;

    ++batch.begin;
  }

  // Setup which texture to use
  glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE0 );
  glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID );
  glUniform1i( texture, 0 );

  glBindBuffer( GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, m_transformBuffer );
  glBufferSubData( GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, 0, sizeof( Transform ) * count, m_transforms );
  glBindBuffer( GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, 0 );

  // Render
  glDrawArraysInstanced( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6, count );
}

glDisableVertexAttribArray( texCoord );
glDisableVertexAttribArray( pos );

glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0 );

glUseProgram( 0 );

glfwSwapBuffers( ENGINE->Window( ) );
```

If I swap the `glBufferSubData` call for a `glBufferData` call then the flickering problem is gone and my scene is rendered as expected. I would really prefer to use `glBufferSubData` if possible, but am just not understanding why I have such an issue.

Edit: This feels to me like a strange synchronization issue. I believe that my transform data is being overwritten at some point by the `glBufferSubData` call while OpenGL did not expect the data to be overwritten yet. I'm guessing it is a driver issue? I have no idea. Everywhere I read online states that `glBufferSubData` should be synchronous.

Edit: I might have found a duplicate: [glBufferSubData between glDrawArrays calls mangling data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897461/glbuffersubdata-between-gldrawarrays-calls-mangling-data)

Edit: After some more research I found [this link](http://onrendering.blogspot.com/2011/10/buffer-object-streaming-in-opengl.html) about asynchronous data upload with buffer orphaning. I believe this should fix my issue since for some reason `glBufferSubData` is not implicitly synchronous. I will come back with details about how it worked out.

**Edit**: I used the solution in [this link](http://onrendering.blogspot.com/2011/10/buffer-object-streaming-in-opengl.html) as an alternative, and all issues have cleared up.

Comment: Where are you actually allocating storage for your texture buffer? You cannot use `glBufferSubData (...)` without first making at least one call to `glBufferData (...)` in order to allocate the data store and setup the usage pattern hint. If you use the wrong hint, you can potentially create coherency and synchronization issues. So including that tidbit is important to answer this question.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I was allocating it properly with `GL_STREAM_DRAW`. I've figured out an alternative method using buffer orphaning in the last link I gave.

Comment: Ah, okay. But be aware that buffer orphaning works by allocating a new data store (actually, it usually reuses an old one, but finding a block to reuse adds overhead) every time. A better solution, as I mentioned in one of the answers you linked to is to map the buffer when you make updates and then call `glFlushMappedBufferRange (...)` when you finish. That gives you much more fine-grained control over synchronization. [This book](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~pcozzi/OpenGLInsights/OpenGLInsights-AsynchronousBufferTransfers.pdf) has an excellent explanation of everything I just mentioned.